# How to make MiniDLNA work with USB Storage devices?

Tags: file-sharing

I have MiniDLNA installed and it's working perfectly. However what I want is MiniDLNA to be able to index files stored on USB Devices as soon as the USB device is plugged in and remove those files from the index as soon as the USB device is removed. I am using `usbmount` to mount USB devices automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just create media_dir for each /media/usb1 /media/usb2 etc inotify should be able to discover new files in those directories and remove them if the directory content disappears.

Comment: But the directory doesn't disappear right? The contents inside of it disappears. Moreover I don't know why but `inotify` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You might need to enable it depending on distribution